# How do I create a second window in Druid?

Tags: rust, druid-rs

I'm trying to create a second window using [druid](https://docs.rs/druid/0.7.0/druid/index.html). I have a button that's supposed to create a secondary window:

```
let enter_btn = Button::new("Enter")
    .on_click(|_ctx, data: &mut HelloState, _env| {
        AppLauncher::with_window(game_window)
            .use_simple_logger()
            .launch((*data).game_state)
            .expect("Failed to launch application");
    });
```

However, I see that this is not possible since I am using `AppLauncher` to do this. I tried searching through the documentation to no avail since most of the structs with the name `Window` just pertains to the Window descriptions and ID and I can't find anything about creating new windows. Is this possible using Druid? If so, what's the best way to open a new window while sharing the same state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`EventCtx::new_window`](https://docs.rs/druid/0.7.0/druid/struct.DelegateCtx.html#method.new_window) for this. `druid` also has [an example](https://github.com/linebender/druid/blob/master/druid/examples/multiwin.rs) for this use case, the relevant part is this:

```rust
let new_win = WindowDesc::new(ui_builder())
    .menu(make_menu)
    .window_size((data.selected as f64 * 100.0 + 300.0, 500.0));
ctx.new_window(new_win);
```